# Fill array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i fill array of arrays, so everytime my loop goes on another array it increases implement?

Currently stuck at this:

```js
function multiplicationTable(row, col) {

    let rowarr = new Array(row);
    for (let i = 0; i < rowarr.length; i++) {
        rowarr[i] = new Array(col);
    }
   
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < col; k++) {
            rowarr[i][k] = k + 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(rowarr)
}


multiplicationTable(3, 5)
```

```
expected output: [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10], [4,8,12,16,20] ... etc.]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really close

just needed to add the row part

```js
function multiplicationTable(row, col) {

    let rowarr = new Array(row);
    for (let i = 0; i < rowarr.length; i++) {
        rowarr[i] = new Array(col);
    }
   
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < col; k++) {
            rowarr[i][k] = (i+1)*(k + 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(rowarr)
}

function powerMultiplicationTable(row, col) {

    let rowarr = new Array(row);
    for (let i = 0; i < rowarr.length; i++) {
        rowarr[i] = new Array(col);
    }
   
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < col; k++) {
            rowarr[i][k] = Math.pow(2,i)*(k+1)
        }
    }
    console.log(rowarr)
}

console.log('multiplicationTable')
multiplicationTable(3, 5)
console.log('powerMultiplicationTable')
powerMultiplicationTable(3,5)
```

Comment: That gives 3,6,9,12,15 in the third sub-array, OP said they wanted 4,8,12,16,20 there.

Comment: oh! took `multiplicationTable` as basis. if the expected response is that other, it looks more like a power of 2 table, right? I'll give a solution for both

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options and here is one of them:

```js
function getTable(rows, cols) {
  return Array.from({length: rows}, (_, rowIdx) => {
    return Array.from({length: cols}, (_, coldIdx) => (coldIdx + 1) * Math.pow(2, rowIdx));
  })
}

console.log(getTable(3, 5))
```

Comment: Code seems very complicated for me, but it works

Comment: Updated the snippet: in your example you said that it should be `1, 2, 4,...`. So, I believe every first item is a power of 2.